# Exercise about Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, laurent-series

I want to solve the following problem

[image]

The way I thought about this problem is to consider the following:

Let $f^*(z)$ be holomorphic on the whole plane but the origin. So it has laurent series
$$f^*(z)=\sum a_n z^n.$$

Let
$$b(z)=e^{2\pi i z}.$$

This function has a range of the upper half plane and moreover, has a period of $1$ Moreover, it is analitic and so

$$f^*(b(z))=\sum c_n {e^{2\pi izn}}=\sum c_n q^n$$

is an analitic function on the upper plane of period of $1$ as ($b(z)=q$). Therfore

$$f(x)=f^*(q)$$

for some $f^*(q)$ as described above. Furthermore,

$$c_n =\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\gamma _r} \frac{f^*(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$

for all $r>0$. We can paremeterize by $z=e^{i\pi(x+iy)}$ with $y$ beeing treated as a constant (dependent on the radius) to get
$$c_n=\int_{0}^{1}f^*(e^{2\pi z})e^{-2\pi i zn}dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(x+iy)e^{-2\pi i zn}dx$$

as required.

**Issues with this:** To me this proof holds as one can always find an analitic function on the complex plane and remove the origin from its domain. However, I checked the answers and the solution that they have seems to be quite different (for the first part)

[image]

**Questions:**

$1$) Does this mean that my solution is wrong?

$2$) Can someone help me understand the first part of their solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first part of the solution: do you know the definition of the complex logarithm? Are you familiar with the notion of winding number, and the reason for $g_{\gamma}(z)$ differing by integer multiples of $2 \pi i$ for different branches of the logarithm?

In any case, the solution explicitly shows the existence of a holomorphic function which injects the punctured plane into all $\mathbf{C}$. The issue with your solution is that you implicitly assume that if there exists some $f^{*}$ such that $f^{*} \circ e^{2 \pi i z} = f(z)$ for any $f(z)$ which is holomorphic on the upper half plane and has period 1. This function is in fact the complex logarithm, and its existence is nontrivial - the solution shows that it is possible to construct a function, and specifically states the domain on which this construction is valid.

A side note: the range of $e^{2 \pi i z}$ is not the upper half plane, but the puncture complex plane $\mathbf{C} \backslash \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I understand how is the logarithm and its branches are defined, however, I do not see how the line that follows, starting with "Since $f$ is periodic ... " is asserted. Could you elaborate on how the "seeing"/deduction is made?

Comment: $g_{\gamma}(z)$ is a holomorphic function from the unit punctured disk, once a branch has been chosen. We know f is periodic with period 1 and holomorphic on the punctured unit disk, then if we compose it with the function $g_{\gamma}(z)$, we get a function that is also holomorphic there. If we proceed to compose this new function, $f^{*}$, with the exponential function ("replace q by $e^{2 \pi i z}$), we recover the original function, $f(z)$, since by construction the logarithm is the (local) inverse of the exponential map.